# What is the point of signature file in signed JAR/ZIP files

Tags: android, java, digital-signature

The way JAR signatures (or ZIP for Android) are designed is that they have a manifest file, containing digest for each file in the archive. Then there is a "signature file" that contains digest of manifest entries, and the digest of the manifest, and then a PKCS#7 signature of the signature file.

So, what's the point of the signature file, is there any drawback to just signing the manifest directly?

Comment: Did I miss something about "*ZIP for Android*"? Because as far as I know, ZIP file in Android is the same as ZIP file on Windows, unless you meant APK?

Comment: Also, the official documentation about [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html). I still haven't any idea about "*why?*", but it seems purely for JAR validation by verifying against file modification.